# Symfony 4 - The autoloader expected class […] to be defined in file

Tags: php, autoload, symfony4

I'm trying to add an old Bundle that I have built on **Symfony 3.*** to **Symfony 4** but I get this error:

> The autoloader expected class
>   "App\SBC\TiersBundle\Controller\ChantierController" to be defined in
>   file
>   "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/HelloSymfony4/vendor/composer/../../src/SBC/TiersBundle/Controller/ChantierController.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/HelloSymfony4/config/services.yaml
>   (which is loaded in resource
>   "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/HelloSymfony4/config/services.yaml").

It seems like the framework did not recognise the namespace of the bundle so I did these steps:
In `config/bundle.php` I added the third line:

```
return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    \SBC\TiersBundle\TiersBundle::class => ['all' => true], // this one
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
];
```

And in `composer.json` I added the first line in `autoload` section:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "SBC\\": "src/SBC/",
            "App\\": "src/"

        }
    },
```

Because the namespace of my Bundle starts with `SBC\`, and I have launched `composer dump-autoload` in the console.

```
<?php

namespace SBC\TiersBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class TiersBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

**ChantierController.php**:

```
namespace SBC\TiersBundle\Controller;

use SBC\TiersBundle\Entity\Chantier;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


class ChantierController extends Controller
{
...
}
```

And this is my Bundle under /src:
[image]

Unfortunately still facing the same error, how can I fix it and thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: `config/services.yaml`:

```
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    SBC\:
        resource: '../src/SBC/*'
        exclude: '../src/SBC/TiersBundle/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'

    SBC\TiersBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/SBC/TiersBundle/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

Comment: Can you show us the `ChantierController.php` contents?

Comment: @JakubKrawczyk I have updated my question please take a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by Symfony configuration and conflict in namespaces. First you need to adjust your `config/services.yaml`:

```
SBC\:
    resource: '../src/SBC/*'
    exclude: '../src/SBC/TiersBundle/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

SBC\TiersBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/SBC/TiersBundle/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{SBC,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

This way you'll define defaults for your namespace and prevent the default namespace `App` to include your directory when generating autoload classes. Note that if you are using annotation routes, you also need to adjust `config/routes/annotations.yaml`:

```
sbc_controllers:
    resource: ../../src/SBC/TiersBundle/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

so the routes are generated correctly. After performing these steps run `composer dump-autoload` again and clear Symfony's cache.

This might be helpful in the future if you run into another problems: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-4.0.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it and give you feedback, and for the type I'm using `yaml` for routes not `annotation` so I should change the type to yaml ?

Comment: If you are using `yaml` for defining your routes it shouldn't be necessary to change anything.

Comment: After changing services.yaml I get this exception: `Invalid "exclude" pattern when importing classes for "SBC\": make sure your "exclude" pattern (../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}) is a subset of the "resource" pattern (../src/SBC/*) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/HelloSymfony4/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/HelloSymfony4/config/services.yaml").``

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake & updated my answer. I believe you need to exclude `../src/SBC/TiersBundle/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}` for the `SBC\` namespace.

Comment: Now a new error : Class Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/HelloSymfony4/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/HelloSymfony4/config/services.yaml").

Comment: That's another problem - I would need to see your services.yaml.

Comment: sorry for my late answer I have updated my question.

Comment: Do you have form component installed? Symfony 4 differs from previous versions, skeleton version keeps only the bare minimum. You need to run `composer require form` first, because your form element probably depends on a nonexistent class.

Comment: you're right now the error is gone and another one rises XD, I'm sorry for wasting your time, this is the new exception: Compile Error: Cannot declare class SBC\TiersBundle\Controller\ChantierController, because the name is already in use

Comment: Try to change the `exclude` section for `App\` namespace to:
`exclude: '../src/{SBC/TiersBundle,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'` - it is most likely colliding in some way. Also be sure that you run `composer dump-autoload` after these adjustments.

Comment: sorry I can't find this `exclude` section in `services.yaml`!

Comment: ah soryy I found it

Comment: Very nice now it works fine and my Bundle is working, Thanks for your time I really appreciate it :)